# Is it possible to get an object's primary key value in a primefaces SelectOneMenu component?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to get an object's primary key (id) property using a selectOneMenu primefaces component? Like the line below;

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="lst_location_name" value="{ejbLocations.location.locationName}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{ejbLocations.locations}" var="loc" itemValue="#{loc.id}" itemLabel="#{loc.locationName}" />                                                      
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In this case, am trying to display the locationName but I want my managed bean to access the objects id property which is a primary key in the database table.

Comment: You have an 'id' as a value in `f:selectItems`, but in the `p:selectOneMenu`, you expect a 'name'? That is inconsistent.

Comment: Based on the comment from Kukeltje:
1) Change 'value' from p:selectMenu to a integer variable and store the id, e.g. value="{ejbLocations.location.locationId}"
2) Use a converter to store the location object, e.g.value="{ejbLocations.location}" plus converter="<implement a location converter>"

Comment: That worked, thanks guys